# ModelInstance >> Material >> Pixmap possible? insane?

Tags: libgdx

Is it possible/practical to get a pixmap from a modal;

ie;
**ModelInstance >> Material >> Pixmap**
possible? insane?

*In short;*

If I have a arbitrary basic textured quad, with one node, one material, one texture can I can a pixmap (with alpha) of that texture in some way?

*Usecase:*

I have a game with pickupable items. These objects are represented in the (essentially 3d) game world by textured quads.
To represent picking up, I was going to change the mouse cursor - which is already manually controlled by a sprite layer rendered ontop of the model layer
It would be useful to be able to thus get the image of the object being picked up so I can quickly just add a little arrow to it and use that.

I *suspect* the answer is "cant be done", or at least not without some ott render-offscreen business.
Now, one workaround I know is just to remember where the image resource originally came from and recreate it for the pixmap.
Before doing that, just want to ensure I am not missing something.

Thanks,
Thomas

Additional note; These images are quite small - 100x100 alpha, no more then one being picked up at a time occasionally. Performance thus isn't much of a concern.

Comment: Using Pixmap is almost never a good idea, that would be over complicating things. But you can render to Framebuffer (aka "FBO" and "render to texture") and use that for your UI or whatever you need it for.

Comment: It would take an immense amount of work for you to work out how to draw a textured model directly to a Pixmap. It would be easier to draw the model to a FrameBuffer and then take a pixmap screenshot of the FrameBuffer. Should be quick enough at only 100x100.@Xoppa I think in this case Pixmap is necessary to convert the image to a mouse cursor. The alternative would be to hide the mouse cursor and drag a sprite around the screen, although that tends to look laggy on desktop.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I tried a few techniques before settling on this. 
Hiding the real cursor and dragging a sprite is what I am using now. Lag actually seems ok. Certainly better then my 1st method which was dragging another 3d quad around.
Using a cursor directly would of course be best speed wise, but I got greedy and wanted more then 1-bit alpha.

btw, just to be clear; Its not the whole model I would need to render to a pixmap - just take its texture. This game as while its technically 3d, its visually 2d/isometric, so mostly everything is just flat images anyway.

Comment: @Xoppa hmm...guess I should learn how to use the FBO then. :) I knew the principles, but never used it in GDX.